# How to get push notification click event with Flutter Huawei Push Kit plugin?

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am integrating Huawei Push Kit (https://pub.dev/packages/huawei_push) in Flutter application and everything works fine except I am unable to get the event when received push notification message is clicked to be able to act on it.

Is this possible to achieve via this plugin or do I need to write this part in native Android code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can achieve this with another plugin that listens for the custom intents. [Uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package from pub.dev is easy to use. Here is a quick guide to uni_links package:

1. Add **uni_links** to your **pubspec.yaml** file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  huawei_push: 4.0.4+300
  uni_links: 0.4.0
```

2. Define an intent filter on your **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<application
  <!-- . . . Other Configurations . . . -->
    <activity/>
      <!-- . . . Other Configurations . . . -->
        <!-- Add the intent filter below.(inside the application and activity tags) -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="app"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application
```

3. Call the uni links methods in your initState() that will listen for the custom intents. The notification's custom intent I've sent from the Push Kit Console looks like this:

```
app:///ContentPage?name=Push Kit&url=https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit
```

```
// Get the initial intent that opens the app
Future<void> initInitialLinks() async {
  // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
  try {
    String initialLink = await getInitialLink();
    if (initialLink != null) {
      var uri = Uri.dataFromString(initialLink);
      String page = uri.path.split('://')[1];
      String serviceName = uri.queryParameters['name'];
      String serviceUrl = uri.queryParameters['url'];
      try {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            page,
            arguments: ContentPageArguments(serviceName, serviceUrl),
          ); // Navigate to the page from the intent
        });
      } catch (e) {
        Push.showToast(e);
      }
    }
  } on PlatformException {
   print('Error: Platform Exception');
  }
}

// Get intents as a stream
Future<Null> initLinkStream() async {
  if (!mounted) return;
  _sub = getLinksStream().listen((String link) {
    var uri = Uri.dataFromString(link);
    String page = uri.path.split('://')[1];
    // Parse the string ...
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(page); // Navigate to a page from the intent
  }, onError: (err) {
    print("Error while listening for the link stream: " + err.toString());
  });
}
```

For more information, visit: [Deep Linking on Flutter using Huawei Push Kit’s Custom Intents](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/deep-linking-on-flutter-using-huawei-push-kits-custom-intents-958fedb7490a)
The [accompanying github repository](https://github.com/atavci/deep_linking_on_flutter_with_huawei_push_kit) of the article includes the codes.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented it like that, but this is actually a workaround. I was hoping there was more direct approach to get the content of the push notification message when clicked or immediately if the app is in foreground as you can do with firebase_messaging. But ok, this solution is good enough :)

Comment: Yes, currently deep linking for Flutter could be achieved by using Huawei Push Kit Plugin along with uni_links package.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked into their flutter plugin and couldn't any method for that. I guess you will have to write platform specific code and for that you can refer to their demo native android project with PushKit.

https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-clientdemo-android